# Query a table view

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

**tblsyslur** (syslur=states)
Fields:  syslaid (pk)
         sysla

**tblhreppar** (hreppar=muncipalities)
Fields:  hrepparid (pk)
         syslaid   (fk)
         hreppur

**tblbæir**  (bæir=cities)
Fields:  bæirid     (pk)
         hrepparid  (fk)
         bæir

I have a query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblhreppar WHERE hrepparid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo utf8_encode("<td>" . $row['hreppur'] . "</td>");
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

Using this query only made it possible for me to get the field hreppur or field hreppurid in my output so I wanted to create a view that combines the three tables so I made this query:

```
create view view_syslurhrepparbæir as 
select tblhreppar.hrepparid, tblsyslur.sysla, tblhreppar.hreppur, tblbæir.bæir
from tblhreppar, tblsyslur, tblbæir
where (tblsyslur.syslaid = tblhreppar.syslaid)
AND (tblbæir.hrepparid = tblhreppar.hrepparid)
order by tblsyslur.sysla;
```

This means that I had a view with the following fields:
**hrepparid,
sysla (state),
hreppur (muncipality),
bæir (city)**

I changed my query to this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM view_syslurhrepparbæir WHERE hrepparid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo utf8_encode("<td>" . $row['hreppur'] . "</td>");
      echo utf8_encode("<td>" . $row['bæir'] . "</td>");
      echo "</tr>";
      }
```

**BUT** - the output from this **only** gives me the value from the field 'hreppur' and not 'bæir'.  I just get an empty line in my table where the 'bæir' value should be situated.

You can see an example here:  http://www.hafdal.dk/test/getuser2.php
Try choosing "Akrahr." from the dropdown and then you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Don't use hungarian notation type prefixes for tables and views. They should be interchangable. At some point you might refactor the table structure and create a view simulating the previous structure so your application code remains unchanged and you will end up with views called `tbl...`

Comment: so does the view work when you use it through your sql tool of choice, maybe baeir is null..

Comment: When I look at the view in mysql it looks fine so I don't get why it doesn't work.

Comment: there must be something in the way the view is created, maybe my query is not clear enough when I create it.  When I create a view with only two tables joined (tblhreppar & tblsyslur), everything works fine.

Comment: View looks ok to me, have you got the foreign keys on. Does select * from Cities for the id you are using find teh right stuff?

Answer (score 0):

try to add "as" to identify an unique field, E.G

```
create view view_syslurhrepparbæir as 
select tblhreppar.hrepparid AS hrepparid, tblsyslur.sysla, tblhreppar.hreppur, tblbæir.bæir
from tblhreppar, tblsyslur, tblbæir
where (tblsyslur.syslaid = tblhreppar.syslaid)
AND (tblbæir.hrepparid = tblhreppar.hrepparid)
order by tblsyslur.sysla;
```

I think doing that you can call it and compare with that value with no problem